# JQuery not appending <li> items to a <ul> list

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, list, razor

**Question Background:**

I have an MVC site that I am passing a list of object to a view which should then build up a  drop-down list programmatically for each item in the list.

I am attempting to build up a drop-down of items as shown in this example (**please note - this is an example and not from my site**):

[image]

**The Issue:**

I iterate around the list of objects passing each one to a script method called 'AddRows'. I can see that the items are being passed but I cannot get the items to append to the list (which has the id CartList).

**The Code:**

The HTML with the id `CartList`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu cart-content" id="CartList" role="menu">
</ul>
```

---

Razor `Foreach` which iterates around the passed object list and calls `AddRow` method supplying the relevant properties:

```
@foreach (var cartItem in (List<LoginTest.Models.CartItem>)ViewBag.Data)
{
<script>
    var cartItemName = '@cartItem.CartItemName';
    var cartItemQty = '@cartItem.CartItemQty';
    var cartItemPrice = '@cartItem.CartItemPrice';


    AddRows(cartItemName, cartItemQty, cartItemPrice)
</script>
}
```

---

The AddRows method which ***should*** append a new list item to the `CartList` list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var AddRows = function (productName, productQty, productPrice) {

    $('#CartList').append('<li><b>' + productName + '</b><span>x ' + productQty + ' £' + productPrice + '</span></li>');

};
</script>
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just do this by calling a `ChildAction`?

Comment: Just to narrow it down the javascript part of things isn't the problem. It works as defined. Problem must be with the Razor component. Functional example using your code http://jsfiddle.net/8jt5ce6g/

Comment: It looks like you are just adding duplicate variables to the global namespace with your foreach. Are you _really_ wanting to create a new script element with 3 global vars for each cart item? They will just overwrite the previous ones.

Comment: @RonGilchrist Thanks for your reply. I thought the code would of just appended each item to the list rather than overwrite the previous item? I've modified the JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/8jt5ce6g/1/) as supplied by Joe W to use a for loop to show this. I apologise in advance if I've misunderstood your comment. I've also added a picture to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: @JoeW Thank for the JSfiddle. I hope you dont mind but I've modified it in response to Ron's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than polluting your html with all this extra inline scripts, you can assign the collection direct to a javascript variable

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var items = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Data))');
    var cartList = $('#CartList');
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
      var li = $('<li></li>');
      li.append($('<b></b>').text(item.CartItemName));
      li.append($('<span></span>').text('x ' + item.CartItemQty + ' £' + item.CartItemPrice));
      cartList.append(li);
    });
  });
</script>
```

However all this could be done easier and with out javascript by using a `ChildAction` that return the menu as a partial view and using `@Html.Action(...)` in the main view

Answer (score 0):

**here is the sample link that works**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/8jt5ce6g/2/
```

**html**

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
Dropdown
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul id="CartList" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">


</ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var AddRows = function (productName, productQty, productPrice) {

$('#CartList').append('<li><b>' + productName + '</b><span>x ' + productQty  + ' £'+ productPrice + '</span></li>');

};

for(i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
{
AddRows('test',''+i+'','100');
```

}